# On the fly website manipulation using

Tags: javascript, html, vba

I am trying to work out if I can alter the functionality of a website preferably through vba (access) or any other way that I can centrally manage.  What I am trying to achieve is, depending on permissions, I would like users to log onto a website and the website is then changed on the fly to stop the user using normal functions of the website.  For example some users have access to a submit button while others do not.

I have seen that you can use VBA to parse websites and auto logon.  I'm just not sure if its capable of doing any local scripting like greasemonkey does.

Maybe I am looking at this wrong and can achieve this at the firewall level instead of running website scripts.

Any ideas?

Comment: To clarify, this is for websites you don't control?  I would think that denying access to those sites outright at the firewall level would be the way to go.  Any machine-local manipulation of the returned content of the site can probably be easily circumvented.

Comment: Regardless of the method you're using, if you only edit the HTML, your page is insecure and vulnerable. Anyone visiting your page can edit the HTML client-side. Look into learning a backend language that runs server side scripts, like python/ruby/php/asp.

Comment: Yes this is for websites that I have no control over.  The problem is that I need to give access to the site so cant just block the whole site through the firewall.

Answer (score 1):

You should not manage website permissions using a client-side technology like JavaScript.  Users can easily either just disable JavaScript/VBScript or tamper with the page.

The best approach is to manage permissions by emitting the HTML from a server-side scripting language such as ASP.Net or PHP.

ASP.Net has built-in, generally adequate support for membership, roles and permissions that would meet this need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy(v=vs.100).aspx

If that is not an option for whatever reason, and you can accept the risk of someone tampering with the permissions you setup, you can certainly use something like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to hide portions of an HTML document that a user should have no access to.  You can accomplish the same thing using JavaScript without jQuery, but I would suggest jQuery because it abstracts away many of the cross-browser issues.

If you do that, hide everything by default and then show selectively based on permissions.  That way, the simplest method of just disabling JavaScript will not reveal anything special (though it is still quite easy to hack).